# IOS dependent sync

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Я не разу не программировал под IOS. Суть такая. Есть приложение которое лежит в Test Flight и у него кончилось 90 дней. На сколько я понял, я должен как то загрузить через xcode новый билд и срок обновится. Но загрузив проект с битбакет он даже не компилится, компилятор ругается на большинство импортов. Так понимаю это как в андройд, пока ты не синхронизировал библиотеки извне в градл, проект не будет о них знать. Как мне решить эту проблему, чтобы хотя бы посмотреть на эмуляторе все ли работает или нет? И если решу, то как мне закинуть новый билд в Test Flight из xcode?

Comment: Какая система зависимостей в проекте? Если Cocoapods, то да, проект не скомпилится, пока не установить поды.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю - да. Но разве они не должны были подключиться сразу, т.к я скачал проект с битбакета? Где я могу их просмотреть/подключить

Comment: Разобрался, удалил проект и по новой подтянул из битбакета, все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Просто измените версия приложения. Увеличьте на единицу. Скорее всего проблема в этом. Вы не можете загружать подряд две одинаковые версии.